# Window.navigator on other browsers in mac os not working?

Tags: javascript, next.js, navigator

I am trying to access the navigator function on my project to share the required URL, but I am not able to access it in Mac OS when it is some other browser than Safari. Is there a way to turn around this issue ?

Here is the function I defined for the share function:

```js
    function shareFunction() {
        if(navigator.share) {
            navigator.share({
                title: document.title,
                url: window.location.href
            })
            .then(() =>{
                setShareClick(true)
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }
    }
```

This works on Safari in Mac OS and every other Windows browsers but not on Mac Chrome or Firefox, how do I produce the share sheet in mac chrome ?

Comment: It works in Safari? What share sheet do you mean? I'm not sure macOS has one

Comment: Have you not checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#browser_compatibility or https://caniuse.com/web-share before asking ...?

Comment: They do have a small popup that you can use as extension isn't it ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this feature is not implemented in all browsers, a new feature perhaps? Look at https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.share to see which browsers support this.

For an alternative you can show a custom share popup this way:

```js
function shareFunction(data) {
    if (navigator?.canShare(data)) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the draft for the spec your condition would properly end up being something like: `if (navigator.share && navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare(data)) { navigator.share(data) } else { ... }`. https://w3c.github.io/web-share/#canshare-data-method

Comment: Shorter equivalent in recent browser:  `if (navigator?.canShare(data)) { ... }`

Comment: I had to use (navigator?.canShare && navigator.canShare(data)) to avoid errors that canShare is not a function

Comment: This means in that case you might need to check explicitly that `navigator?.canShare` actually is a function, cause `navigator?.canShare(data)` and `navigator?.canShare && navigator?.canshare(data)` is the same thing.